# How to categorize values from one list based on threshold values in other one?

Tags: python, list, sorting, list-comprehension

I would like to categorize values in one list based on threshold values in other list. In other words, I would like to compare list items one by one with threshold values in list - one by one and get output list of categories.

```
input:
Values = [9999, 3000, 400, 9999, 1000] - it is variably long due to input data
Threshold = [10000, 5000, 1500, 800, 0] - also will be changed, so have to be variable - but always sorted descending to 0

Expected output (categories' numbers should be based on index):
cat = [0,1,3,0,2]
```

I'm persuaded it might be done with advanced list-comprehension, which I am not so familiar with. So I've tried:

```
val_cat = []
thres_len = len(Threshold)
for item in Values:
     for vis in range(0,thres_len - 1):
          if Threshold[vis+1] < int(item) <= Threshold[vis]:
             val_cat = val_cat + [vis]
          else:
             pass
```

This way is neither pythonic nor functional, but best I could have tried, as I studied only basics of VB several years ago.

Thank you for your help! I believe it is a piece of cake for this community :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean to make it a list comprehension, here you go:

```
cat = [next(i-1 for i,t in enumerate(Threshold) if t <= v) for v in Values]
```

But you will expect this:

- Last threshold `Threshold[-1]` must be less than everything in `Values` (i.e., absolute lower bound)
- This is not fast: O(mn) for m the size of `Values` and n the size of `Threshold`. A more efficient algorithm will be to do binary search on `Threshold` for each value

Therefore, you might want to implement your own function to replace the `next()` above, to address the above two points.